# Is there a single noun to indicate "the ordering (row-major or column major) used in an array"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a single noun that indicates unambiguously (to a computational scientist, at least) "the ordering ([row-major or column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)) used in an array"?

For instance, the term [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (or sometimes even the odd-sounding [byte sex](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/byte-sex.html)) refers to whether a word is stored in little-endian or big-endian order, and one single English word is enough to convey this meaning. I would not consider "the ordering of an array" clear enough by itself without the parenthetical, by contrast.

Comment: Are you looking for a word like _ columnwise_? From [Matlab](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f22019): "MATLAB stores data in a column-major (columnwise) numbering scheme, which is how Fortran stores matrices. "

Comment: @MauroVanzetto No. I am looking for a word with which you can fill the gap in the following sentence: "Matlab stores data columnwise, C stores them rowwise; so they have different ______".

Comment: "storage order"?

Comment: memory *layout*?

Comment: @GoHokies I like your suggestion, "memory layout".

Comment: Several links refer to the "storage order", see https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-6.html or http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that a slightly modified version of @GoHokies suggestion **array layout** or even a more precise, but a bit wordish **array memory layout** should suffice and be unambiguous.

In my opinion, this term is the clearest one, describing what *row-major* and *column-major* (and possibly some other variants) is.

Google search (Apr 7, 2018, google.ca):

- "array memory layout" - 2080 results with 100% of all first 10 results and images being to the topic
- "array layout" - 67500 results with only 3/10 directed at different areas of science (say, "array layout methodology for VLSI circuits"). So I would say it is safe to use
- "memory layout" results in a much larger #hits, but only 1/10 is relevant for the topic of the discussion
- "storage order" results in more than 100000  hits; however, a lot of them lead to a different (slightly or completely) areas.

For papers:

- [This](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2747875) uses a term "data layout" to generalize, but talks particularly about the ways arrays are stored in memory.
- [This](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mithuna/pubs/ics99.pdf) particularly discusses the "array layouts".

Though I doubt that any computational scientist or an average programmer would be confused by a term **storage order**, that is used wider.